# Help with the name of this puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, puzzle-identification, twisty-puzzles

When I was cleaning my basement I found one puzzle that my father gave me when I was a child.

I really want to know the name of it! Could someone help me?

The puzzle consist in 4 disks, and each disk have 4 balls. To beat the puzzle you have to put balls with the same color in the same column.

here is some pictures:

[image: Puzzle]

[image: Puzzle]

Comment: I knew it as a Smarties puzzle, as branded versions were given away as a prize for buying several packs of that brand of chocolate (UK)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That specific one looks like a Varikon tower to me. See

- http://www.cs.brandeis.edu/~storer/JimPuzzles/MANIP/VarikonTowers/VarikonTowers.pdf
- http://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/tower.htm

Comment: It seems you are right. This is a Varikon Tower, which is basically a simplified version of the Babylon Tower. Good catch :)

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be called "Tower of Babel" or "Babylon Tower".
Some sites refer to it as a "Hungarian Tower of Babel", others as "Ivory Tower".

- http://www.passionforpuzzles.com/2012/09/hungarian-tower-of-babel-puzzle.php
- http://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/ivory.htm

The puzzle was designed by Endre Pap and [patented](http://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/patents/de3104021.pdf) on 2 December 1982.