# What is the name (and brand / year) of this puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-identification, twisty-puzzles

First a bit of background. I'm a collector of twisty puzzles. I've been collecting them for almost 3.5 years now. [Here is my current collection of 209 puzzles.](http://twistypuzzles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=26889)

As you may be able to tell by the linked collection thread, I like to catalogue my puzzles with their respective brand/producer and year (if pre-2005). There are a few puzzles of which I don't know the brand or year. That doesn't matter too much, although if anyone has any information about [the producer/year of those](http://twistypuzzles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=30037) I would also appreciate it.

For one puzzle however, I'm unable to find the name. I bought it from eBay with the title "Interweaving Rings Puzzle - London, England", but I know that this is not the official name of the puzzle, and the seller also didn't knew the name. I haven't got a response on the TwistyPuzzles Forum yet, but after seeing [Help with the name of this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23796/help-with-the-name-of-this-puzzle) I thought that perhaps someone here knows.

[image]

It's an equator-type puzzle with sliding tiles, and (as correctly pointed out by the eBay seller) an 'interweaving rings' puzzle.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After searching around, going through Hungarian Rings, I finally stumbled on **Radosza's Rings**, which seem to be educational toys. [Link](http://www.radoszarings.com/eng/turista_eng.html)

Comment: Looks right to me - Radosza's Tourist Rings, to be precise.  Those are interesting.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thanks a lot, really appreciated.