# Identifying this cube

Tags: rubiks-cube, puzzle-identification

I have a MoYu cube that goes quite well, but I am unsure what model it is. I have looked everywhere, but to no avail. Pictures for the cube and its insides have been provided. Thanks in advance!
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this has nothing to do with the creation and solving of puzzles. This question doesn't belong on PE so it will be closed soon. Anyway, welcome to PE! Please take the tour: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: As @Adam states, this doesn't really belong here. Getting help for identifying twisty puzzles in general, like [this post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28922/what-is-the-name-and-brand-year-of-this-puzzle) or [this post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23796/help-with-the-name-of-this-puzzle) is fine, but the brand/model of a regular 3x3x3 Cube is a bit off-topic here. You could ask it on [the Cubers-reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Cubers/) perhaps; in their Daily Discussion Thread for questions without much discussion like this.

Comment: I'm voting to leave open because [tag:puzzle-identification] questions are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The Rubik's cube here is very similar(Maybe even same) to the one in the photos.

https://www.rubiks.com/rubik-s-speed-cube-3x3.html

It is known as Speed Cube, and according to the same website,

> *"This is the fastest speed cube we’ve ever created. It emerged from the
>   knowledge, expertise and spirit of two great speedcubing powerhouses:
>   Rubik’s and Gan."*

Comment: No, it does not seem to be. I’ve asked on Reddit, and it was identified as a Guanlong Plus. The overall design of the RSC (Rubik’s Speed Cube) is also very different from mine, most obvious difference being the presence of a logo on the RSC, compared to mine, which has none. Thank you for trying to help however!